# Setting proxy while using express-msteams-host

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Can you tell me how can I configure the proxy while using `@BotDeclaration` from [`express-msteams-host`](https://github.com/wictorwilen/express-msteams-host)?

Basically, my server's network traffic must be routed via a proxy URL because I have a URL whitelisting in place. I'm just looking for a similar option while using this package.

Something like this: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/src/IClientOptions.ts#L29 (I'm using this for Microsoft Graph API)

`express-msteams-host` internally trying to reach `https://login.botframework.com` and that is where the issue is. My server is inside a corporate network and without specifying a proxy option the package can not connect to `https://login.botframework.com`

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: The BotDeclaration only specifies the local endpoint (path) of the server. It does not have anything to do on how things are routed to the server.

Comment: got the same thread-https://github.com/wictorwilen/express-msteams-host/issues/23